# Why is USB copying photos to PC unreliable?

Tags: iphone

I do it through Explorer by dragging and dropping the files from DCIM.

It usually fails part way through. When I restart the copy, one file is corrupted so I have to delete the 2nd attempt and restart again. Repeat until everything's copied.

[image: copy fail error]

Also, thumbnails sometimes don't match the file contents. If you copy a photo based on the thumbnail, it can become a different photo on the PC with the same file name.

Generally, why is it so bad? Am I supposed to change a setting or is this workflow just  the wrong way to copy photos and never works properly?

Comment: It's been a while since I touched a PC with an iPhone but I believe that iTunes (still) manages syncing on Windows and can sync all pictures for you and return all the errors at the end that you can save as a text file. I believe that iTunes for Windows is in the MS App store and also as a direct download from Apple. They are both the same app, just depends on your preference for downloading.

Comment: I'm aware there's Itunes and Windows Photos app but I'm trying to find about about plain file copying.

Comment: The iPhone is not a flash drive. Apple does their best to make that kind of usage difficult or at least problematic. Yeah you **can** store files on the iPhone. But it isn't *designed* for it and most of the people we see here trying to use the iPhone as a flash drive end up frustrated and confused. To borrow from pop culture. It's Apple, this is the way.

Comment: How many files are you trying to copy?

Comment: About 400 photos and videos taken each month. It can almost never copy the whole 400 without failing. but a few dozen is OK.